# Access ControllerBase.Request and ControllerBase.Response from Service in ASP.NET CORE 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

If I have a service, `IService`, that needs to access the Request or Response objects given by ControllerBase like I would in a controller:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> HelloWorldAsync() {
    Response.Cookies.Append("Hello World", "Goodbye World");
    return Ok();
}
```

How would I access `Response` from within a service? What would I need to inject? Or do I need to resort to passing it through the  method of the service, like so:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> HelloWorldAsync() {
    await _myService.FooWithCookies(Response);
    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ConfigureServices` code, you'll want to ensure you're adding the HTTP Context accessor:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

And then in your service you can inject it:

```cs
public class MyService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

    public MyService(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public async Task FooWithCookies()
    {
        HttpRequest request = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;
        HttpResponse response = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Response;
    }
}
```

Note that `IHttpContextAccessor` is registered as singleton, which can be useful in some situations.

See more info in the documentation: [Use HttpContext from custom components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components)

---

Depending on what your actual needs are, you might want to look at implementing a custom [`IActionResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iactionresult?view=aspnetcore-6.0), which contains a method with the following signature:

```cs
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task ExecuteResultAsync (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionContext context);
```

This gives you access to the context via `ActionContext`, and also includes details of the specific action being executed.

Then `FooWithCookies` could return it (e.g. `return new MyActionResult(someConstructorParameter);`) and then you could simply pass it on in the action (e.g. `return await _myService.FooWithCookies();`).

Answer (score 2):

If you need the `Request` or the `Response` then you may inject an [`IHttpContextAccessor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.ihttpcontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-6.0) into you service through ctor injection.

```cs
public class YourService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public YourService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var response = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response;
    }
}
```

In your `Startup.cs` file:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

    // rest is omitted for clarity.
}
```